# Connection to MYSQL in my dockerized project suddenly goes wrong

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, laravel-8

I have this one dockerized laravel app along with it's following service:

1. Mysql
2. Redis
3. Meilisearch

here is the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /home/alifzhorif/docker_stuff/mysql://var/lib/mysql

  search:
    image: getmeili/meilisearch:latest
    container_name: search
    hostname: search
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MEILI_NO_ANALYTICS=true
      - MEILI_NO_SENTRY=true
      - MEILI_ENV=development
      - MEILI_MASTER_KEY=random123
    ports:
      - 7700:7700
    volumes:
      - /home/alifzhorif/docker_stuff/search:/meili_data

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - /home/alifzhorif/docker_stuff/redis:/data

  idhome:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/docker/idhome:latest
    hostname: idhome
    container_name: idhome
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      - DOMAIN=xxxxxx.xxxxx
      - OPCACHE_ENABLE=Off
    volumes:
      - /home/alifzhorif/docker_stuff/idhome:/app/current
      - /home/alifzhorif/docker_stuff/idhome/storage:/app/storage
```

the problem part is on the Mysql, this happened when i tried to rebuild the docker and this happened when i rebuild them

and when i inspect the Mysql log here are the latest log before it crashed/stopped:

```
2024-03-07 15:00:42 2024-03-07T08:00:42.230856Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4000!
2024-03-07 15:00:42 2024-03-07 08:00:42 0x7f0d2b70b880  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139694540109952 in file ut0ut.cc line 921
2024-03-07 15:00:42 InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
2024-03-07 15:00:42 InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
2024-03-07 15:00:42 InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
2024-03-07 15:00:42 InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
2024-03-07 15:00:42 InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
2024-03-07 15:00:42 InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
2024-03-07 15:00:42 InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2024-03-07 15:00:42 08:00:42 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
2024-03-07 15:00:42 This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
2024-03-07 15:00:42 or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
2024-03-07 15:00:42 or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
2024-03-07 15:00:42 Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
2024-03-07 15:00:42 As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
2024-03-07 15:00:42 collection process might fail.
2024-03-07 15:00:42 
2024-03-07 15:00:42 key_buffer_size=8388608
2024-03-07 15:00:42 read_buffer_size=131072
2024-03-07 15:00:42 max_used_connections=0
2024-03-07 15:00:42 max_threads=151
2024-03-07 15:00:42 thread_count=0
2024-03-07 15:00:42 connection_count=0
2024-03-07 15:00:42 It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
2024-03-07 15:00:42 key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68199 K  bytes of memory
2024-03-07 15:00:42 Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
2024-03-07 15:00:42 
2024-03-07 15:00:42 Thread pointer: 0x0
2024-03-07 15:00:42 Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
2024-03-07 15:00:42 where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
2024-03-07 15:00:42 terribly wrong...
2024-03-07 15:00:42 stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xf11adb]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x486)[0x79f7d6]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf630)[0x7f0d2b2ee630]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f0d29601387]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f0d29602a78]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld[0x76f748]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0xfd)[0x10e96dd]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld[0x11a13d2]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld[0x11a191b]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld(_Z6fil_ioRK9IORequestbRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmmPvS8_+0x208)[0x11ad148]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0xe4)[0x115b4a4]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x42d)[0x112a87d]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld(_Z31trx_rseg_get_n_undo_tablespacesPm+0x15d)[0x10c883d]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld[0x1090668]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x3996)[0x1094db6]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld[0xf5a8a0]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x51)[0x7f2671]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld[0xcf2b85]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld(_Z40plugin_register_builtin_and_init_core_sePiPPc+0x2f0)[0xcf8eb0]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld[0x797cc4]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0xa85)[0x79b4e5]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f0d295ed555]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 mysqld[0x78f154]
2024-03-07 15:00:42 The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
2024-03-07 15:00:42 information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.207430Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.208583Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.43) starting as process 1 ...
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.219502Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.220227Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.220231Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.220232Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.220233Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.220235Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.222824Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.224855Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.264444Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.364309Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.365897Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07T08:00:47.395899Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4000!
2024-03-07 15:00:47 2024-03-07 08:00:47 0x7f7608306880  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140144920258688 in file ut0ut.cc line 921
2024-03-07 15:00:47 InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
2024-03-07 15:00:47 InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
2024-03-07 15:00:47 InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
2024-03-07 15:00:47 InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
2024-03-07 15:00:47 InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
2024-03-07 15:00:46 2024-03-07 08:00:46+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.43-1.el7 started.
2024-03-07 15:00:46 2024-03-07 08:00:46+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-03-07 15:00:46 2024-03-07 08:00:46+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.43-1.el7 started.
2024-03-07 15:00:46 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
2024-03-07 15:00:47 InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
2024-03-07 15:00:47 InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2024-03-07 15:00:47 08:00:47 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
2024-03-07 15:00:47 This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
2024-03-07 15:00:47 or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
2024-03-07 15:00:47 or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
2024-03-07 15:00:47 Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
2024-03-07 15:00:47 As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
2024-03-07 15:00:47 collection process might fail.
2024-03-07 15:00:47 
2024-03-07 15:00:47 key_buffer_size=8388608
2024-03-07 15:00:47 read_buffer_size=131072
2024-03-07 15:00:47 max_used_connections=0
2024-03-07 15:00:47 max_threads=151
2024-03-07 15:00:47 thread_count=0
2024-03-07 15:00:47 connection_count=0
2024-03-07 15:00:47 It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
2024-03-07 15:00:47 key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68199 K  bytes of memory
2024-03-07 15:00:47 Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
2024-03-07 15:00:47 
2024-03-07 15:00:47 Thread pointer: 0x0
2024-03-07 15:00:47 Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
2024-03-07 15:00:47 where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
2024-03-07 15:00:47 terribly wrong...
2024-03-07 15:00:47 stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0xf11adb]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x486)[0x79f7d6]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf630)[0x7f7607ee9630]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f76061fc387]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f76061fda78]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld[0x76f748]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0xfd)[0x10e96dd]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld[0x11a13d2]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld[0x11a191b]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld(_Z6fil_ioRK9IORequestbRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmmPvS8_+0x208)[0x11ad148]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld(_Z13buf_read_pageRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_t+0xe4)[0x115b4a4]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id_tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x42d)[0x112a87d]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld(_Z31trx_rseg_get_n_undo_tablespacesPm+0x15d)[0x10c883d]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld[0x1090668]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld(_Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv+0x3996)[0x1094db6]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld[0xf5a8a0]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x51)[0x7f2671]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld[0xcf2b85]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld(_Z40plugin_register_builtin_and_init_core_sePiPPc+0x2f0)[0xcf8eb0]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld[0x797cc4]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0xa85)[0x79b4e5]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f76061e8555]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 mysqld[0x78f154]
2024-03-07 15:00:47 The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
2024-03-07 15:00:47 information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

i am currently trying for several ways alternative:

1. checking the logs then identify the ibdata1. -> which now i am asking
2. replacing it with the mysql server in the WSL itself instead from docker, by create user and grant all privileges